# JS Spread Operator to normal form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I have the following code that includes Spread Syntax in JS

```
const opposite = function (f) { return (function (...args) { return !f(...args) }) };
```

can it be converted without using Spread Syntax? It seems that if I do use this, some of the js minification tools fail to parse these lines of codes.

Comment: From [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) online: `const opposite = function opposite(f) { return function () { return !f.apply(void 0, arguments);};};`.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object in combination with [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

The `arguments` object exist inside every function call and it represents the arguments to the function. Using this we can capture any and all arguments passed to the function.

The `apply` method on the other hand allow you to call a function by passing an array to represent the arguments.

Combining both we can do this:

```
const opposite = function (f) {
    return (function () {
        return !f.apply(null, arguments)
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

would be to use the apply method, like this:

```
const opposite = function (f) { 
    return function () { 
        return !f.apply(this, arguments); 
    }
};
```

Another way to achieve the same result would be to use the call method and pass the arguments object to the function, like this:

```
const opposite = function (f) {
    return function () {
        return !f.call(this, ...arguments);
    }
};
```

Both of these methods allow you to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the function without using the spread syntax.